# Retrieve database values to textboxes whenever listbox selected index changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

so I just want to view the values from my database to some textboxes in my project whenever the selected index of listbox changes

I have these code but whenever I click an item on my listbox, none of the textboxes displays a data or anything

```
                protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringHRMS"].ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                string selectone = "SELECT * FROM Applicant WHERE ApplicationNo = '" + ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectone, conn);

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    asln.Text = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                    asfn.Text = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                    asmn.Text = reader["MiddleName"].ToString();
                    ashea.Text = reader["HEA"].ToString();
                    astitle.Text = reader["Title"].ToString();
                    aspos.Text = reader["Position"].ToString();
                    asaddress.Text = reader["Address"].ToString();
                    asbday.Text = reader["Birthday"].ToString();
                    asgender.Text = reader["Gender"].ToString();
                    asage.Text = reader["Age"].ToString();
                    asht.Text = reader["Height"].ToString();
                    aswt.Text = reader["Weight"].ToString();
                    asemail.Text = reader["Email"].ToString();
                    ascontact.Text = reader["ContactNumber"].ToString();


                }

                reader.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: check that reader has some data or not?

Comment: you need to debug your code by yourself at every point and check is there any thing strange anywhere. Coz from here its tough to say what's going wrong their. One more thing, dont forget to check tables for the data also